# Unable to retrieve Messages from AWS SQS queue using Boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

My python code looks like :

```
import json
import boto.sqs
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message
from boto.sqs.message import RawMessage


sqs = boto.connect_sqs(aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
q = sqs.create_queue("Nishantqueue")  // Already present


q.set_message_class(RawMessage)
results = q.get_messages()
ret = "Got %s result(s) this time.\n\n" % len(results)

for result in results:
        msg = json.loads(result.get_body())
        ret += "Message: %s\n" % msg['message']

ret += "\n... done."
print ret
```

My SQS queue contains atleast 5 to 6 messages... when i execute this ... i get output as this and this is on every run, this code isn't able to pull the mssgs from the queue :

```
Got 0 result(s) this time.

...done.
```

I am sure i am missing something in the loop.... couldn't find though

Comment: How do you know the queue contains 5-6 messages?  Have you confirmed that via some other tool?

Comment: AWS GUI , i inserted them manually as well as via boto

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same region in the code above as in the AWS console?  Because you are actually calling ``create_queue`` this code would just create a new, empty queue in any region you run it in.

Comment: Yes it is, and the create_queue method won't create a new queue until i specify a visibility_timeout attribute

Comment: That is incorrect.  The ``visibility_timeout`` parameter to ``create_queue`` is optional.  If you call it with just a queue name, it will create the queue if it does not yet exists.

Comment: isn't working that way though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is retrieving messages from an Amazon SQS queue, but it doesn't seem to be deleting them. This means that messages will be invisible for a period of time (specified by the `visibility_timeout` parameter), after which they will reappear. The expectation is that if a message is not deleted within this time, then it has failed to be processed and should reappear on the queue to try again.

Here's some code that pulls a message from a queue, then deletes it after processing. Note the `visibility_timeout` specified when a message is retrieved. It is using `read()` to simply return one message:

```
#!/usr/bin/python27

import boto, boto.sqs
from boto.sqs.message import Message

# Connect to Queue
q_conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-2")
q = q_conn.get_queue('queue-name')

# Get a message
m = q.read(visibility_timeout=15)
if m == None:
  print "No message!"
else:
  print m.get_body()
  q.delete_message(m)
```

It's possible that your messages were invisible ("in-flight") when you tried to retrieve them.

Comment: thanks for the help.. this works.. though i didn't wanna delete my messages